# Poincare lemma via Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

I found such a beautiful proof of Poincaré lemma [here (in Russian)](http://lj.rossia.org/community/ljr_math/8445.html):

> Let $B$ be a star-like neighborhood of 0 in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $r=\sum x^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$. Then Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_r$ will be surjection on $B$ (*it is easy to prove for really-analytic forms in coordinates*) and one can consider $\mathcal{L}_r^{-1}$. Then for any $\omega$ with $d\omega=0$$$\omega=\mathcal{L}_r \mathcal{L}_r^{-1}\omega=(di_r+i_rd)\mathcal{L}_r^{-1}\omega=d(i_r\mathcal{L}_r^{-1}\omega)$$

But I do not understand why $d\omega=0$ implies $$d\mathcal{L}_r^{-1}\omega=0 \text{ or at least } i_rd\mathcal{L}_r^{-1}\omega=0?$$

Could you help me to understand it? I feel a bit uncomfortable about details in this blog, but the result should be right, it seems to be a verifiable resource.

Comment: If $\mathcal{L}_r$ is only a surjection, why can we consider $\mathcal{L}_r^{-1}$?

Comment: Lie derivatives commute with the exterior derivative (which can be seen easily using the Cartan formula used to get the third equation).  I assume (I'm not 100% sure on this point outside the setting of groups, although it should be easy to prove) that if two maps commute, then the maps also commute with each other's inverses (if they exist).

Comment: [Here](http://verbit.ru/MATH/GEOM-2013/pde-en-11.pdf) is a more recent problem set that might be useful

Comment: @YuriVyatkin Thank you!

Comment: A detailed proof in this vein can be found in L. Nicolaescu, Lectures on the Geometry of Manifolds, p.215 (look for "Speculations around the Poincaré lemma")

Answer (score 0):

Alas, the whole idea is wrong: $r(0)=0$, so $\mathcal{L}_r (\theta)(0)=0$, but not every closed from $\omega$ has $\omega(0)=0$.

Comment: Your conclusion is not quite right: the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_X$ is not linear in $X$, and values of it in nearby points may contribute to a non vanishing derivative.